# Visual Studio 2010 - code coloring inconsistency

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio 2010 I've noticed this below shown code coloring inconsistency - anyone who can tell me why the second and last `modGlobal` are not colored?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this too. Happens sometimes and seems to be a bug. When you try to edit the code a little bit (adding new lines, cut/paste) the color coding will return.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Visual Studio 2010 SP1`? if not try getting SP1 for VS2010, that will probably solve the problem.